# 20.04 Software Updater no longer listing repos as it downloads from them

Tags: 20.04, update-manager

Sometime in the last couple of weeks the software updater in my my 20.04 system changed.

Before the change, when you started it manually it would list each repository it was downloading a list of package information from. (At least, that's what I think it was doing.)

Now, when you start it manually you see a message saying "waiting for packagekitd to exit" and no visual indication of which repos it is downloading from. After that it goes on to behave as it did before, loading the software list, displaying a list of available packages to install, and so on.

I have changed no settings or anything else related to the software updater. The only thing that I've been doing is applying all available updates regularly. In fact I manually run the updater every morning when I boot up and apply everything it has to offer. So the system has all the most recent packages as far as I know.

If this is a deliberate change, that's fine, but it's an odd one. Depending on your network and how busy the software repos are you can stare at that packagekitd message for some time before it comes back and goes on to the next step. In fact, the first time I noted it I thought something was stuck, exited the updater, and tried it again. During the second attempt I was more patient and things went on fine, but continued to look different, as described above.

If this is not a deliberate change, how would I change it back? What would have happened to cause this behaviour, given I've done nothing to make it happen?

Thanks!

--- edited 11/27/20 to add more details in response to the first comment ---

/var/log/syslog has only this error from  software-updater:

```
Nov 27 11:39:36 zaphod zeitgeist-datah[2918]: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:210: Error during inserting events: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.zeitgeist.EngineError.InvalidArgument: Incomplete event: interpretation, manifestation and actor are required
```

I reinstalled python3-update-manager, update-manager-core, and update-manager via the synaptic package manager and re-ran update-manager. The above error is still present.

However I cannot tell if the packagekitd message is still happening or not. Given the repository data was updated just a few minutes before there is nothing being downloaded and the message (if it is present at all) goes by so quickly I cannot even see it.

I will retry software-updater sometime later (probably tomorrow morning when repos have changed so new package lists need to be downloaded) and report back here once I have that answer.

Actually, I will include the entire output from /var/log/syslog for the update-manager run here to be thorough, and because I see some sort of DNS issue happening in there as well now that I look deeper:

```
Nov 27 11:34:28 zaphod zeitgeist-datah[2918]: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:210: Error during inserting events: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.zeitgeist.EngineError.InvalidArgument: Incomplete event: interpretation, manifestation and actor are required
Nov 27 11:34:28 zaphod systemd[1753]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Nov 27 11:34:29 zaphod dbus-daemon[909]: [system] Activating service name='org.debian.apt' requested by ':1.255' (uid=1000 pid=11085 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/update-manager " label="unconfined") (using servicehelper)
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod AptDaemon: INFO: Initializing daemon
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod org.debian.apt[11100]: 11:34:30 AptDaemon [INFO]: Initializing daemon
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod dbus-daemon[909]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.debian.apt'
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod AptDaemon: INFO: UpdateCache() was called
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod org.debian.apt[11100]: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker/pkworker.py:35: PyGIWarning: PackageKitGlib was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PackageKitGlib', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod org.debian.apt[11100]:   from gi.repository import PackageKitGlib as pk
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod org.debian.apt[11100]: 11:34:30 AptDaemon [INFO]: UpdateCache() was called
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod AptDaemon.Trans: INFO: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/b862decf962e42cba77ebb616e2b0708
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod org.debian.apt[11100]: 11:34:30 AptDaemon.Trans [INFO]: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/b862decf962e42cba77ebb616e2b0708
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/b862decf962e42cba77ebb616e2b0708
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod org.debian.apt[11100]: 11:34:30 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/b862decf962e42cba77ebb616e2b0708
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/b862decf962e42cba77ebb616e2b0708
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod org.debian.apt[11100]: 11:34:30 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/b862decf962e42cba77ebb616e2b0708
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Updating cache
Nov 27 11:34:30 zaphod org.debian.apt[11100]: 11:34:30 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Updating cache
Nov 27 11:34:31 zaphod systemd-resolved[677]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Nov 27 11:34:31 zaphod systemd-resolved[677]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Nov 27 11:34:32 zaphod dbus-daemon[909]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.258' (uid=0 pid=11469 comm="/usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedeskto" label="unconfined")
Nov 27 11:34:32 zaphod systemd[1]: Starting PackageKit Daemon...
Nov 27 11:34:32 zaphod PackageKit: daemon start
Nov 27 11:34:32 zaphod dbus-daemon[909]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Nov 27 11:34:32 zaphod systemd[1]: Started PackageKit Daemon.
Nov 27 11:34:41 zaphod AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/b862decf962e42cba77ebb616e2b0708
Nov 27 11:34:41 zaphod org.debian.apt[11100]: 11:34:41 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/b862decf962e42cba77ebb616e2b0708
Nov 27 11:35:27 zaphod systemd[1753]: gnome-launched-update-manager.desktop-11085.scope: Succeeded.
```

--- edited on 11/28 to add more ---

Reran software-updater this morning. The problem remains unchanged.

My system was still tricking through the stuff that happens after the boot, but here is the contents of /var/log/syslog while the updater was running:

```
Nov 28 08:17:25 zaphod zeitgeist-datah[3163]: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:210: Error during inserting events: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.zeitgeist.EngineError.InvalidArgument: Incomplete event: interpretation, manifestation and actor are required
Nov 28 08:17:25 zaphod systemd[1811]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod dbus-daemon[841]: [system] Activating service name='org.debian.apt' requested by ':1.196' (uid=1000 pid=3954 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/update-manager " label="unconfined") (using servicehelper)
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod AptDaemon: INFO: Initializing daemon
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod org.debian.apt[3973]: 08:17:28 AptDaemon [INFO]: Initializing daemon
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod dbus-daemon[841]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.debian.apt'
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod AptDaemon: INFO: UpdateCache() was called
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod org.debian.apt[3973]: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker/pkworker.py:35: PyGIWarning: PackageKitGlib was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PackageKitGlib', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod org.debian.apt[3973]:   from gi.repository import PackageKitGlib as pk
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod org.debian.apt[3973]: 08:17:28 AptDaemon [INFO]: UpdateCache() was called
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod AptDaemon.Trans: INFO: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/c70d7e23ecbb49ae8307fc3f51ca51d1
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod org.debian.apt[3973]: 08:17:28 AptDaemon.Trans [INFO]: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/c70d7e23ecbb49ae8307fc3f51ca51d1
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/c70d7e23ecbb49ae8307fc3f51ca51d1
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod org.debian.apt[3973]: 08:17:28 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/c70d7e23ecbb49ae8307fc3f51ca51d1
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/c70d7e23ecbb49ae8307fc3f51ca51d1
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod org.debian.apt[3973]: 08:17:28 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/c70d7e23ecbb49ae8307fc3f51ca51d1
Nov 28 08:17:30 zaphod AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Updating cache
Nov 28 08:17:30 zaphod org.debian.apt[3973]: 08:17:30 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Updating cache
Nov 28 08:17:31 zaphod systemd-resolved[648]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Nov 28 08:17:31 zaphod systemd-resolved[648]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Nov 28 08:17:35 zaphod AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/c70d7e23ecbb49ae8307fc3f51ca51d1
Nov 28 08:17:35 zaphod org.debian.apt[3973]: 08:17:35 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/c70d7e23ecbb49ae8307fc3f51ca51d1
Nov 28 08:17:43 zaphod systemd[1811]: gnome-launched-update-manager.desktop-3954.scope: Succeeded.
```

I see the same error as before:

```
GDBus.Error:org.gnome.zeitgeist.EngineError.InvalidArgument: Incomplete event: interpretation, manifestation and actor are required
```

and this warning:

```
Nov 28 08:17:28 zaphod org.debian.apt[3973]: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker/pkworker.py:35: PyGIWarning: PackageKitGlib was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PackageKitGlib', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
```

I am discounting the NXDOMAIN items as some research yesterday tells me they are probably nothing to be concerned about.

I am no expert on this, but nothing here looks all that significant to me, and probably does not explain the behavior I am seeing.

Comment: Unable to duplicate the behavior: On my up-to-date Ubuntu 20.04.1 test system, Software Updater displays the repos instead of a packagekit message. Check your /var/log/syslog for error messages. Consider reinstalling the `update-manager` package.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the problem description with what I found in response to your suggestions.